# Child Theme activates, but nothing from parent theme displays (MAMP, Multisite)

Tags: multisite, child-theme

I searched for a solution for this problem, but cannot find an answer (or exact replica of the problem)

Basically, I set up Multisite on MAMP Pro (Apache port 80, MySQL Port 3306). The set up was smooth, and I created a new site via a subdirectory.

The parent theme loads fine. I created a child theme, and it activates (it doesn't show a broken message). On the Appearance page it shows the message "This theme requires the parent theme", but underneath the Theme Description.

However when I view the front page of the site, the page is blank, and there is no html at all.

Would could possibly be the error? I spent a few hours on this already and it's not going really well. Code of child theme, only CSS, no functions.php or other php files in the child theme folder.

```
/*
Theme Name: Confit Child Theme
Author: Automattic
Template: confit
Description: Confit Child Theme 1
Version: 1.0
*/

@import url('../confit/style.css');
```

- Should also mention that the parent functions are not loading either.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this happens only in this theme? What if you make a TwentyEleven child? Enable [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) as well. And other errors may appear in the PHP error log, viewable in the Console app.

Comment: Hi brasofilo, Thank you for the suggestion. Enabling the error log showed where the exact problem was occurring. Basically in the wp-config file, I was specifying a default theme upon any site install. The default theme was a child theme, so I read when using a child theme as the default, you have to specify the parent folder. The error was `Constant TEMPLATEPATH already defined in /Volumes/Home/Websites/wp-includes/default-constants.php`. The code I used was `define('WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'confitchild');
define( 'TEMPLATEPATH', '/public_html/wp-content/themes/confit');`

Comment: Glad to hear it's sorted out and to see you posted a detailed solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I am using a child theme as the default theme every time a new blog is created. In the wp-config.php file - I was calling

```
define('WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'confit-childtheme');
define( 'TEMPLATEPATH', '/public_html/wp-content/themes/confit');
```

I read that when you are using a child theme as the default install theme, you have to reference the parent theme folder. This was the **error**.

The error I received while debugging was
`Constant TEMPLATEPATH already defined in /Volumes/Home/Websites/wp-includes/default-constants.php`

So I removed the 2nd line, and the child theme displays correctly while also being the default theme upon new blog installs.

Thank you brasofilo